# How to get input from a HTML form into my Python script

Tags: python, django

So guys, I am using Django right now to test some stuff out.
So what I want to do is I have a HTML form which takes a input from a user,
I want to pass this input to my python script to do something with this input, how do i do this?

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1> League of Legends Rank lookup</h1>
     <div id ="ranklookup"> 
         <form name="search" action="" method="get">
               Search: <input type="text" name="summoner">
               <input type="submit" value="Submit">
         </form> 
     </div>
{% endblock %}
```

My Python script is rankfinder.py I want to use the value of 'summoner' in my python script to do something with this input, How do I do this in Django?

Comment: Please checkout this documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/

Comment: I checked that out already but didnt find what I was looking for

Comment: can you make this clear what you want. 1) way to use the value in your script. 2) way to create django view to do this. ?

Comment: So basically what I want to do is: This form is in home.html which is a template in my Django project. I want to use the input of the input field from this form in my rankfinder.py and later pass it back toi my html file ( I guess I do this by importing render in my python script and pass that variable to my html file?)

Comment: The tutorial answers all your questions. You should read it again.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply passing the input value to view using request.get here is an example :

```
def yourview(request):
     inputValue = request.GET.get('summoner')
```

Or you can use ajax :
in html :

```
var form = $("#your_form_id")
form.submit(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault() 
   var inputValue = $("#your_input_id").val()
   data = {
     inputValue : inputValue
   }
   $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "{% url 'your_view_function' %}",
        dataType:'json',
        data:data,
     }
   success: function(data) {
      do_something
   }

}
```

in view :

```
def yourview(request):
   inputValue = request.GET.get('inputValue')
   // make what u want
   return JsonResponse({"ok":"ok"})
```

Comment: he doesn't want django view, what he want is a way to read that HTML from a python script.

Comment: Indeed thats what i was looking for ,.Im fairly new in Django, can I jsut put my python script into the view or just put the code of that script into the view, is that possible?